# GUI.Box z-index for mouseover

Tags: unity, depth

So I am drawing an inventory with slots like so:

```
private void DrawItemSlotAndAttachActions(Item currentItem, Rect slotRectangle, Event e, int itemSlotPosition)
    {
    if (!(currentItem is EmptyItem))
        {

            GUI.depth = 0;
            GUI.DrawTexture(slotRectangle, currentItem.Icon);
            if (slotRectangle.Contains(e.mousePosition))
            {
                _tooltip = currentItem.CreateTooltip();
                _showTooltip = true;

                DragAndDropItem(e, itemSlotPosition);
                UseConsumable(e, currentItem);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DropItemOnEmptySlot(slotRectangle, e, itemSlotPosition);
        }
    }

    public void OnGUI()
    {
        _tooltip = ""; //reset every time...can this be done better?
        GUI.skin = Skin;

        DrawItemSlotAndAttachActions(.....);
        ShowTooltip();
    }

    private void ShowTooltip()
    {
        if (_showTooltip)
        {
            GUI.Box(new Rect(Event.current.mousePosition.x, Event.current.mousePosition.y, 200, 150), _tooltip,
                Skin.GetStyle("Tooltip"));
        }
    }

    private void HideToolTipWhenEmpty()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_tooltip))
            _showTooltip = false;
    }
```

In here I have the problem that when I hoven over an item, all the boxes that are drawn **after** are on top of my tooltip Box.

How can I make sure that the box is drawn **on top** of all the rest?

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, it is still behind the rest of the buttons.

Comment: I assume you have good reasons for sticking to the legacy UI instead of the new UI.

Comment: Since I am new to Unity, mind explaining what you mean by "new" UI?

Comment: This ONGUI method of creating Unity is old one. With Unity 4.6, we have new UI feature. In the learn section of Unity3D website, you will find tutorials about it. Main benefit is you don't place the elements through code. You create your UI in the editor itself. https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/the-new-ui

Comment: dont use unity's old onGui, its a bad practice to draw UI elements in runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [GUI.depth](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI-depth.html)

The sorting depth of the currently executing GUI behavior. It's the equivalent of CSS's `z-index`.

Set this to determine ordering when you have different scripts running simultaneously. GUI elements drawn with lower depth values will appear on top of elements with higher values (ie, you can think of the depth as "distance" from the camera).

Your box should have the **lowest** `depth` value.

```
// slots
GUI.depth = 0;
GUI.DrawTexture(...);

// box; to be rendered on top of the slots
GUI.depth = -1;
GUI.DrawTexture(...);
```

Comment: But this requires me to have an OnGUI on all my slots right? And then pushing them all back. Is there a way to do it on the fly? Because I want to be able to only draw the box on mouseovers.

Comment: You should be able to use `GUI.depth` in your case as well. Check my updated answer.

Comment: So I did it as you suggested, I'll update my question with a screenshot.

Comment: Does that box has higher depth than all the rest? Have you tried drawing it last?

Comment: drawing it last does work, thank you. But this makes me put my string of tooltip which I use to check whether or not to hide the tooltip to be put back to an empty string every time in OnGUI. Is there a better way to go about this? See my question for updates. Also why does the depth not work as you suggest? I tried it alot.

Comment: I made an error in my initial post. Your box should have the **lowest** `depth` value.

Comment: That keeps putting the box behind the rest of the later drawn elements. I will keep it at rendering last but I'll have to find a better way in the end.